# VBA code that adds responsive Shapes to the current macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new at coding but I've been asked to create some macro using VBA to speed up our working process in my company.

i have this code that performs a comparison macro:

```
Sub Compare_numbers()
    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim L, M, txt As String
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        L = Cells(i, "L").Value
        M = Cells(i, "M").Value
        
        If L = M Then
            txt = "they are equal"
     
            
        ElseIf L > M Then
            txt = "L is greater than M    " & _
                       ChrW(&H2B61)
             
                        
        Else
            txt = "L is less than M          " & _
                       ChrW(&H2B63)
        End If
        
        Cells(i, "N") = txt
    Next i
End Sub
```

this is the output of the code:
[image: code output]

I need to add to this macro another piece of code that would replace all the arrow characters with a proper Shape from "Insert" tab (and also it should be responsive to the changing of cell's size) like the one in this sample picture:

[image: arrow and bullet shape]

Any idea to do this?

Comment: While this is feasible, wouldn't it be better to use some of the possibilities of conditional formatting?

Comment: unfortunately not, it's a sort of mandatory requirement

Comment: What do you mean by "arrow characters" (to be replaced)? And where should the code searching for? In column F:F?

Comment: @AlexD. I really recommend to have a look into the conditional formattings. They were made exactly for this case. Anyting you try to do with shapes will be really cumbersome and you would need to make sure that nobody can move the shapes accidentally. Also If you want that to change with the values you would need to remove "old" shapes before adding new ones. This will get really slow if the amount of data increases. • Who ever decided that this is mandantory should re-think if this approach is practicable or ends up in a non-responsive slow sheet.

Comment: @FaneDuru don't consider the columns from the second picture, it was just an example to show the  arrow and bullet shapes i would need. With "arrow characters" i mean the output of this part of code: "L is greater than M    " & _ ChrW(&H2B61).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ  trust me, i agree 100% with you, i tried to explain to my supervisors but it's a specific customer request. At this point i don't care about slowness, it's their business.
Any help to do this?

Comment: @AlexD. The issue with your question then is, that you did not show any attempt to solve this on your own. A list of requirements is not a question that can be answered. Asking for whole projects is a way too broad. And this cannot be solved in a *simple* code. As I said before this will become very cumbersome. Give it a try yourself and come back if you have a **specific** question (according [ask]) that can be answered.

Comment: Fully agree to @Pᴇʜ: I would estimate 1-2 days of work for an *experienced* VBA programmer. If you are a beginner, you will have a hard time. But if your management is willing to let you work on this, start with trying to figure out how to add a shape, how to modify shapes properties, then about events in VBA. Start coding and if you are really stuck, raise a specific question. Your current question is far to broad for SO, and SO is not a (free) coding service.

Comment: I started preparing an answer, but since your question has been closed, it does  not accept answers, anymore. So, try placing another question. if I will be available and you will tag me, I can continue what I started...

Comment: @FaneDuru i sent you an mail, thanks

Comment: No need to send any mail... My mail is anyhow configured to reject any account not being on my list. I put accounts on the list when I request a mail message. But, I can see you already accepted the answer. I think it was a wise decision...

Comment: @FaneDuru yes but i would like  to see your answer you had started, please

Comment: How to see it? Please, place another question mentioning that you want this solution type. Anyhow, I do not have time now to deal with it. If you place another question and tag me, I will post the code (finalized, I hope) when I will be home (in some hours..). In principle, the code must check if such an array exists in the cell, then to 'see' if it is the appropriate type, delete if not and insert a new appropriate one, placing it according to the cell Left, Top, Width, Height properties.

Comment: Arrow not array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a helper column N with the formula

```
=IFERROR((L:L-M:M)/ABS(L:L-M:M),0)
```

it will show

- `-1` if `L < M`
- `0` if `L = M`
- `1` if `L > M`

You can then easily use conditional formatting to show the arrows:

[image]

You can even hide the values if necessary so only the arrows are shown in N (just edit the rule accordingly).

---

I highly recommend not to use shapes for that as this will become very cumbersome, can easily fail and will put a heavy load on your sheet if the arrows have to change with the values automatically.

Also you would need to ensure that the shapes cannot be moved accidentally, because this would *"destroy"* the entire sheet.